# c3 js plotting multiple set of data on y axis w.r.t x axis, how to avoid same values not displaying on chart

Tags: c3.js

i am using c3.js to plot 3 set of data on y axis and time stamp on x axis. Is there any way to avoid same values overlapping on one another. Need to display all 3 set of data irrespective of same values. Thanks in advance

Comment: You could stack them if a line or area chart, or draw them as a bar chart which separates the series. http://c3js.org/samples/chart_bar_stacked.html

Comment: Thanks @mgraham. Is there any way to capture history of data like 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year with zoom option. Something like this https://www.amcharts.com/demos/intraday-data/. I need to plot data every second.